# Stock SYMBOL by company name? Yahoo callback doesn't seem to work anymore

Tags: yahoo-finance, stockquotes

I was trying to get the stock Symbol (ticker) once I know the company name. I read quite a few questions here and all of them seemed to suggest that we could use this URL before:

http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=yahoo&callback=YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback

When I hit that page I get an Invalid Response error, page not available.

Do you know if there's an alternative to either have this working or get the Stock SYMBOL in a different way once we have the company name?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the call has been changed. 'lang' and 'region' parameters have been added.

Try this, http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=yahoo&region=US&lang=en-US&row=ALL&callback=YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback

Comment: Hey Bob, that's really useful and working, many thanks!!!

Out of curiosity, how did you find that out? I would have never thought about adding some more parameters and even if I had, how could I guess what they could use... 

Did you use any tool? And where is this callback executed from the front end so that we can see what's actually being sent?

Comment: Glad to help! I was frustrated too and kept Googling until I found a question on SO where somebody posted this query but with a different problem. I wonder how he/she found it out! I'm sorry, I don't really know where the callback is executed.

Comment: I see, thanks for the help!! I kept on looking without much success for hours... marking it as the solution.

Hopefully it'll help other people as well going forward, many thanks mate!

Comment: anyone found a way to get the currency out of that url?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way (without paying) is to use the [OATS-reportable list](http://oatsreportable.finra.org/OATSReportableSecurities-SOD.txt) from FINRA.  Updated daily, it basically includes every symbol traded in the US and is authoritative because it comes from the SRO in charge of equities trading.

Comment: I wanted to say thank you to this response as well. I was not aware about this FINRA website, so that links and the explanation is really helpful as well.... I'll have to have a look and see if I can somehow use it in my end, thanks you for sharing Laplie!